Was wäre die beste Übersetzung von „all around him"?
Eigentlich bin ich hierher vom Deutschen gekommen: Ich hatte es vor, die deutsche Phrase „rings ihm herum" in einem Aufsatz zu schreiben, die, meines Erachtens, „all around him" ähnlich sein sollte.  Aber ich traute mich nicht.  Daher habe ich diese deutsche Phrase nachgeschlagen und es scheint, dass sie nicht korrekt ist, al menos konnte ich ihn nicht finden.  Ich habe allerdings die Phrase „um ihn herum" gefunden, was mir ganz gut scheint, wenn ein bisschen einfacher, aber ich verstehe nicht, warum „ihn" im Akkusative steht.
Dementsprechend kann jemand mir sagen, was die beste Übersetzung von „all around him" wäre, und ob „rings ihm herum" überhaupt trifft?  Und würde man „um ihn herum" bei einem Fall verwenden, wobei wir von etwas Unbewegliches sprechen (ein Mann steht in einem Gebäude, z.B.), nicht etwas, wobei es eine Richtung gibt (sie fuhren ihr Auto um die Stadt herum)?

In Ulm, um Ulm, und um Ulm herum :) A classic tongue twister.

Genau!  Das hat man mir vor vielen Jahren beigebracht.

All around him übersetzt sich zu "überall um ihn herum".
Es steht im Akkusativ weil die Präposition "um" den Akkusativ verlangt.
Eine hoffentlich vollständige Liste bietet Wikipedia im Kapitel "Bedeutungseigenschaften" auf dieser Seite: Wikipedia: Präposition.
Dein "Rings ihm herum" ist nicht korrekt und muss "Rings um ihn herum" lauten.
Du kannst um ihn herum sowohl im Falle einer Bewegung als auch im Falle des Stillstandes verwenden.
Stillstand:
Überall um sich herum kann er die Wände des Gebäudes sehen.
Bewegung:
Sie fuhren ihr Auto um die Stadt herum.

Wie Homer Simpson sagen würde: Doh!  Das hätte ich bestimmt wissen sollen.  Ich habe so sehr an die Wechselpräpositionen gedacht.
